# Error in Swift: "Could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolationSegment."

Tags: xcode, swift

In the following line of code I am adding a row to the 'places' array consisting of map coordinates and a title:

```
places.append(["name": self.title, "lat": "\(newCoordinate.latitude)", "lon": "\(newCoordinate.longitude)"])
```

I get an error: "Could not find member 'convertFromStringInterpolationSegment'."

I would be thankful if someone could help. Let me know if you would like to see more of the code.

Comment: Can we see the definition of `places` and the creation of `newCoordinate`?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for responding. The relevant code is:  var places = [Dictionary<String, String>()]       var newCoordinate = myMap.convertPoint(touchPoint, toCoordinateFromView: self.myMap)